# Visual Studio 2013 - Debug and Release applications in bin folder do not run

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I would like your help please. Outline: Applications which I created runs fine within Visual Studio but doesn't outside Visual Studio.

I created a self hosted WCF application. It worked when it was launched from within Visual Studio 2013.

After I did a rebuild, I would go to the bin folder (either Debug/Release) and run the console from there and it would not run. I double clicked the application and my explorer window freezes up. My arrow cursor has a circle icon that constantly spins. I thought it was a problem with the BaseAddress.

But now, I discover that in either Debug/Release folder, even running an application with a line that prints "Hello world"

```
namespace Demodemo
{
class Program
{
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
           Console.ReadLine();

       }
   }
}
```

I ran the above code and it worked from within Visual Studio. However, it doesn't run from the debug nor release folders.

I used the "Run as Administrator" option for all versions of the application. No joy.

I have Windows 7. I used a framework 4.5.

I opened up Windows Task Manager to kill the process "Demodemo.exe" but it remains there.

The only thing I have change is forcing Visual Studio to run as Administrator every time I double click the icon.

Would you have any idea why is happening?

Comment: Avast has turned viral, uninstall asap.

Comment: I do have Avast Internet Security 2015 installed.

Comment: Thanks Hans, Avast was the problem.

Comment: I did a bit of research of Avast. Apparently, turning off DeepScan fixes the problem..